# Using an observation value to reference a column in the same table in SAS

Tags: sas

I am working in SAS Enterprise guide and have a table as follows:

```
period       year_1       year_2        year_3 
1            100          200           300
2            100          200           300 
3            100          200           300
```

I want to reference a column along the lines of:

```
data table;
    set input;
    chosen_year = year_%eval(period);
run;
```

So the value of the `period` column should determine the result of the `chosen_year`column. How can I do this?

Comment: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/242-30.pdf

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. This question is actually much easier.

Comment: I largely agree with @Tom, though the presence of Community in the closing list means the OP accepted it as a duplicate... hmm.  I can reopen, though, I think.

Comment: Another solution is to use VVALUEX() to obtain value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `period` variable as an array index.

Arrays in SAS are simply collections of variables.  So here you can assign `year_1 - year_3` to an array (it will then put `year_1 year_2 year_3` in that array) and use `period` to choose the 'period_th' entry in the list.

If it is more complicated than the above variable names, you have other options (including, possibly, the originally linked duplicate - though for the above question, that duplicate was overkill).

```
data table;
    set input;
    array year[*] year_1-year_3;
    chosen_year = year[period];
run;
```